# full text label on Boxplot, with added mean point

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

Am trying to get text label similar to what this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8206/labeling-boxplots-in-r, but I cant get it to work. MWE similar to what I have is this:

```
data <- data.frame(replicate(5,sample(0:100,100,rep=TRUE)))

meanFunction <- function(x){
return(data.frame(y=round(mean(x),2),label=round(mean(x,na.rm=T),2)))}

ggplot(melt(data), aes(x=variable, y=value)) +
geom_boxplot(aes(fill=variable), width = 0.7) +
stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom="point",colour="darkred", size=4) +
stat_summary(fun.data = meanFunction, geom="text", size = 4, vjust=1.3)
```

That produces something like "A" in the attached image, and I am trying to get something like "B" for each of the boxes. Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my attempt. First, I reshaped your data. Then, I produced your boxplot. I changed the size and colour of text for mean. Then, I looked into the data that ggplot used, which you can access using `ggplot_build(objectname)$data[[1]]`. You can see the numbers you need. I selected necessary variables and reshaped the data, which is `df`. Using `df`, you can annotate the numbers you want.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)
mydf <- data.frame(replicate(5,sample(0:100,100,rep=TRUE)))

mydf <- gather(mydf, variable, value)

meanFunction <- function(x){
return(data.frame(y=round(mean(x),2),label=round(mean(x,na.rm=T),2)))}

g <- ggplot(data = mydf, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = variable)) +
     geom_boxplot(width = 0.5) +
     stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point",colour = "darkred", size=4) +
     stat_summary(fun.data = meanFunction, geom ="text", color = "white", size = 3, vjust = 1.3)

df <- ggplot_build(g)$data[[1]] %>%
       select(ymin:ymax, x) %>%
       gather(type, value, - x) %>%
       arrange(x)

g + annotate("text", x = df$x + 0.4, y = df$value, label = df$value, size = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks..this works perfectly for me.. only made a subtle change to  `label = round(df$value, 2)` cos the data I have round up to many digits..

Comment: @kenniy I am glad to hear that this works well for you, mate. :)

Answer (score 2):

First, I would take your data and then calculate all the boxplot features yourself. Here's one way to do that

```
dd <- data.frame(replicate(5,sample(0:100,100,rep=TRUE)))

tt <- data.frame(t(sapply(dd, function(x) c(boxplot.stats(x)$stats, mean(x)))))
names(tt) <- c("ymin","lower","middle","upper","ymax", "mean")
tt$var <- factor(rownames(tt))
```

I'm sure there are prettier ways to do that with `dplyr` but this point is you'll need to calculate those values yourself so you know where to draw the labels. Then you can do

```
ggplot(tt) + 
   geom_boxplot(aes(x=var, ymin=ymin, lower=lower, middle=middle, upper=upper, ymax=ymax), stat="identity", width=.5) + 
   geom_text(aes(x=as.numeric(var)+.3, y=middle, label=formatC(middle,1, format="f")), hjust=0) +
   geom_text(aes(x=as.numeric(var)+.3, y= lower, label=formatC(lower,1, format="f")), hjust=0) +
   geom_text(aes(x=as.numeric(var)+.3, y= upper, label=formatC(upper,1, format="f")), hjust=0) + 
   geom_text(aes(x=as.numeric(var)+.3, y= ymax, label=formatC(ymax,1, format="f")), hjust=0) + 
   geom_text(aes(x=as.numeric(var)+.3, y= ymin, label=formatC(ymin,1, format="f")), hjust=0) + 
   geom_point(aes(x=var, y=mean)) + 
   geom_text(aes(x=as.numeric(var), y= mean, label=formatC(mean,1, format="f")), hjust=.5, vjust=1.5)
```

to draw each of the labels

[image]