# ggplot - adding labels to a box plot created from pre-computed values

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

given a dataframe `df` like below.

```
df <- data.frame(x=c("A","B"), min=c(1,2), low=c(2,3), mid=c(3,4), top=c(4,5), max=c(5,6))
```

Using ggplot, one can create a box plot like below

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, ymin = min, lower = low, middle = mid, upper = top, ymax = max)) +
  geom_boxplot(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

I need to add the labels for the five points in the boxplot (just outside the box on the right side of each box) - how do I go about this ?

Note - this is about getting the labels from the pre-computed boxplot point data different from the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28225777)

**Update:**

The answer provided by www works on the original dataset. However when I try on a different but similar dataset, it gives error.

```
text <- "
test,group,varType,X25th,X50th,X5th,X75th,X95th
Test1,A,varC,20,25,2.0,35,65
Test1,A,varD,2,3,0.2,5,9
Test1,B,varC,30,35,3.0,45,75
Test1,B,varD,8,9,0.8,11,15
"
plotDat <- read.table(textConnection(text), sep=",", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

# for labels
plotLabels <- plotDat %>% gather(Col, Val, -c(test, group, varType))

ggplot(plotDat, 
       aes(x = group, ymin = X5th, lower = X25th,
           middle = X50th, upper = X75th, ymax = X95th,
           fill=group)) +
  geom_boxplot(stat = "identity") +
  geom_errorbar() +
  facet_wrap( ~ varType, scale = "free_y")  + 
  geom_text(data = plotLabels, aes(x = group, y = Val, label = Val),
            nudge_x = 0.1, nudge_y = 0.3)
```

The error I'm getting is `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'X5th' not found`

Comment: what 5 points are you referring to ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [full text label on Boxplot, with added mean point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28225777/full-text-label-on-boxplot-with-added-mean-point)

Comment: @erocoar, I take it's the "min", "low", "mid", "top", and "max" in `df`

Comment: @EricFail - that question uses `stat_summary` from the underlying data - here the values are pre-computed.

Comment: @erocoar - min = 5th percentile, low - 25th percentile, mid = 50th percentile, top = 75th percentile, max = 95th percentile

Comment: The [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28225777/full-text-label-on-boxplot-with-added-mean-point/28226927#28226927) of the linked question should solve you problem. There the summary stats are explicitly calculated and then added to the plot. So you simple leave out the first step.

Answer (score 4):

We can convert the `df` to long format and then use `geom_text` to plot it.

```
library(tidyr)

df2 <- df %>% gather(Col, Val, -x)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_boxplot(stat = "identity", 
               aes(x=x, ymin = min, lower = low, middle = mid, upper = top, ymax = max)) + 
  geom_text(data = df2, aes(x = x, y = Val, label = Col), nudge_x = 0.1, nudge_y = 0.3)
```

[image]

We can also use `geom_label`.

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_boxplot(stat = "identity", 
               aes(x=x, ymin = min, lower = low, middle = mid, upper = top, ymax = max)) + 
  geom_label(data = df2, aes(x = x, y = Val, label = Col), nudge_x = 0.1, nudge_y = 0.3)
```

[image]

Not sure if you want to add the text of statistics (`min`, `low` ...) or the actual numbers (`2`, `3`, ...), but for the latter case, simply put `label = Val` will work

Comment: this works on the test data in OP. However in a similar but different dataset, adding `geom_text` as you mentioned gives error `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'X5th' not found`. I'm updating the OP with that data.

Comment: @user3206440 Thanks for your comment. I don't have time for further investigation for now. If you want, perhaps you can ask a new question with the updated dataset.